# How to make an angled tooltip pointer element using CSS?

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I am wondering how to make an angled element that acts as an arrow, attached to a tooltip. I've seen this done by Google Accounts, and I have attached a screenshot. It appears they are achieving this with a couple of `span` elements.

I can't figure out from their HTML/CSS how they did it... My only idea is to use a CSS3 rotation on a regular div, or an image, but I'm guessing there's a more basic way.

Can anyone give me a hint? I'm not looking for a full solution, I'm just stumped about how to approach it. Also it's not about the tooltip itself, it's about that angled element.

[image]

EDIT: [Here's a related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355177/tooltip-arrow-right?rq=1) They are using transparent borders, border-radius and box-shadows?

Comment: Take a look at [Tooltipster](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/) source. I think it might have what you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm I'm looking at their little pointers... They also use 2 spans for it, but I can't tell from their CSS how it's done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create it using image or manipulated span, I know facebook create it using sprite image, google and twitter using styled span, just make border transparent except the bottom one. this is twitter:

[image]

[this is a tutorial](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/slopes).